# Does the 0.8.2 Kafka Producer manage partitioning for you?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a hard time understanding what (if anything) is the equivalent of the 0.8.0 "partitioner.class" configuration property in the new 0.8.2 producer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe form `0.8.2` they have introduced `org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord<K,V>` which takes a topic name an optional partition number, and an optional key and value. You can typically use it like

```
    ProducerRecord<String,String> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<String,String>(topic, key, value);
```

[From the doc](http://kafka.apache.org/082/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerRecord.html)

> If a valid partition number is specified that partition will be used when sending the record. If no partition is specified but a key is present a partition will be chosen using a hash of the key. If neither key nor partition is present a partition will be assigned in a round-robin fashion.